# Vuex Modal with promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, vuex

I am currently having a modal on my root app that watches for a vuex state change and shows/hide content accordingly like so,

```
// inside my modal
computed: {
 modal() {
  return this.$store.state.modal
 }
}
```

In any component, etc that I need to launch a modal. I just need to change the modal state like so.

```
this.$store.commit( 'updateModal',
 {
  title: 'this is the modal title',
  message: 'this is the modal message.'
 }
)
```

This all works great. But if I want the okay and cancel button to run some function. I'm wondering how I should do this. The best way I would imagine would have the modal return a resolve or reject so my component can continue with its own function. But I have no idea how to hook it up since my modal and my component is so far separated.